# Delete an image in PHP (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I have this code which uploads an image from admin and it works well.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'register_and_build_fields');
function register_and_build_fields() {
    register_setting('theme_options', 'theme_options', 'validate_setting', 'delete_file');
}
function validate_setting($theme_options) {
         $keys = array_keys($_FILES); $i = 0; foreach ( $_FILES as $image ) {  
         // if a files was upload 
         if ($image['size']) {  
         // if it is an image  
         if ( preg_match('/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/', $image['type']) ) {       $override = array('test_form' => false);    
         $options = get_option('theme_options');  echo "<img src='{$options['logo']}' />";
         // save the file, and store an array, containing its location in $file 
         $file = wp_handle_upload( $image, $override );       $theme_options[$keys[$i]] = $file['url'];     } else {   
         // Not an image.     
         $options = get_option('theme_options');       $theme_options[$keys[$i]] = $options[$logo];   
         // Die and let the user know that they made a mistake.   
         wp_die('No image was uploaded or invalid format.<br>Supported formats: jpg, jpeg, png, gif.<br> Go <button onclick="history.back()">Back</button> and try again.');     }   }   // Else, the user didn't upload a file.  
         // Retain the image that's already on file.   
         else {     $options = get_option('theme_options');     $theme_options[$keys[$i]] = $options[$keys[$i]];   }   $i++; }
         return $theme_options;
}
```

and now I want the function to delete the current image.

```
     function delete_file($theme_options) {
     if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_FILES)) {
      $image = $_FILES['delete_file'];
      if (file_exists($image)) {
        unlink($image);
        echo 'File '.$image.' has been deleted';
      } else {
        echo 'Could not delete '.$image.', file does not exist';
      }
    }
    }
```

I added the button in admin but is doing.. nothing.
I'm building a `TemplateOptions` in WordPress and now I'm trying to make the logo function to be uploaded and deleted from admin. Like I said, uploading the logo works and now I want to make the field "delete" to work.

Comment: `$_FILES` will not hold any information unless you are actively uploading files, like when you upload the logo. I would need to see more of the code to be able to help you further.

Comment: This is all I got to show, the rest has nothing to do with image upload/delete. I'm thinking maybe if I make the uploaded file to specific folder and be named for ex. "logo".jpg/png/gif and the delete function to delete the file "logo" from that folder. But I don't know how to do that either. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you don't need to insert the record in the `DB` as you only have a single image and whose `name` and `path` are also `constant` . So you simply need to `unlink` the image from the directory and it will be deleted, nothing else.

say your `logo.png` is in your themes's img folder then you should unlink it like this. `default` is your theme name

```
$path = ABSPATH.'wp-content/themes/default/img/logo.png'; 
if(file_exists($path))
{

unlink( $path  );

}
```

`Note:` Remember that you have to pass the absolute path to the `unlink()` and not the `url` having `http` , because it will give you an error , you can't use `http` with unlink.

Comment: I got the theory but couldn't figure out how to do it in my code. I've seen a lot of various examples but none could fit into my code.
Like I said above, I was thinking to rename the uploaded file (logo.jpg) so it will be easier to delete it. If you think this is an easier solution and can help me, I'd appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Adeel but it's not working. I think it must be somehow connected with the upload function, which I posted above.

Comment: if you have a `logo.png` attachment uploaded then this function will work , check your `wp_posts` table and search for `logo.png` in `post_content` col.

Comment: Stil not working. I checked and there is no logo.png in wp_posts. Maybe because the image is not uploaded in a post? I need my upload function to also rename the file in logo.png/jpg/jpeg so after that I can create a function that will delete that file. Any suggestions?